# Java JButton Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am developing an app in Java for selecting the buttons on the screen with the help of an eye tracker. In the app the user will be populated with many buttons. This app basically a quiz. The problem is that I am only able to select one button on the screen, whereas I want to be able to select buttons one after the other. There is a linked list that stores the JButton values in my program

```
protected LinkedList<JButton> _targetItems = new LinkedList<JButton>();
```

Then I am adding buttons to the linked list by doing : `_targetItems.add(a);`. 
The first button i.e. "button a" works by getting selected, whereas when I try to add another button, by doing the same, `_targetItems.add(startbutton);`, it will not get selected. Kindly help!!
Below is the code
{
    protected int correctCount;

```
protected int wrongCount =0;

protected String question = "Kindly Select an Alphabet for a Question";

protected double result;

protected  long startTime, finishTime, timeSpent;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4018966808764793017L;

/**
 * Variable for the feedBackCursor.
 */
protected boolean feedBackCursor = true;

/**
 * Variable for the number of targetItems.
 */
protected int numberOfTargetItems = 6;

/**
 * Variable for the relational size of the targetItems.
 */
protected int buttonHeightRatio = 15;

/**
 * Variable for the relational empty space between the targetItems on the screen.
 */
protected int deadSpace = 10;

/**
 * Stores a reference to the SelectionTriggerType. This variable is initialized with the KeyboardTriggerMechanism.
 */
protected SelectionTriggerType selectionTriggerType = SelectionTriggerType.KeyboardKeyC;

/**
 * Variable for the dwelltime in milliseconds. Recommended value: one second = 1000.
 */
protected int dwellTimeInMilliseconds = 1000;

/**
 * Variable is a upper bound for the variance of all valid gaze points for the given dwell time.
 * Only if the variance is under this value, a TriggerEvent will be generated by the DwellTimeTriggerMechanism.
 * Recommended value: 400.
 */
protected int dwellTimeAccuracy = 400;

/**
 * Variable for the lower bound for the wink time. Only if one eyelid is closed for at least this value in milliseconds,
 * a TriggerEvent will be generated by the WinkTriggerMechanism.
 * Recommended value: 300 milliseconds.
 */
protected int winkTimeInMilliseconds = 300;

/**
 * Queue for storing received GazePoints from the rawGazeDataProvider for the last 5 seconds.
 */
protected ConcurrentLinkedDeque<GazePoint> _rawGazePoints = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<GazePoint>();

/**
 * Queue for storing received GazePoints from the filteredGazeDataProvider for the last 5 seconds.
 */
protected ConcurrentLinkedDeque<GazePoint> _filteredGazePoints = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<GazePoint>();

/**
 * This variable stores a reference to the GazeDataFuture object which stores future GazePoints from the rawGazeDataProvider.
 */
protected GazeDataFuture rawGazeDataFuture = null;

/**
 * This variable stores a reference to the GazeDataFuture object which stores future GazePoints from the filteredGazeDataProvider.
 */
protected GazeDataFuture filteredGazeDataFuture = null;

/**
 * Gives the number of GazePoints which are used to compute the recent location if a TriggerEvent happened.
 */
protected int numberOfGazePointsForRecentLocationComputation = 60;

/**
 * Gives the minimum number of future GazePoints until a screenShot is taken.
 */
protected int minimumNumberForFutureGazePoints = 10;

/**
 * Gives the maximum number of future GazePoints which will be painted on the screenshot.
 */
protected int maximumNumberForFutureGazePoints = 1000;

/**
 * This variable stores the filtered location of the GazePoints which are used to indicate the trigger position.
 */
protected Point recentLocation = new Point();

/**
 * This list stores all valid GazePoints which were used to compute the recent location.
 */
protected LinkedList<GazePoint> _validGPbeforeTrigger = new LinkedList<GazePoint>();    

/**
 * If this flag is set, future GazePoints were recorded. This requires more time after the TriggerEvent because the takeScreenshot method waits
 * until the minimumNumberForFutureGazePoints is reached.
 */
protected boolean storeFutureGazeData = true;

/**
 * This list stores the targetItems. In this implementation JButtons.
 */
protected LinkedList<JButton> _targetItems = new LinkedList<JButton>();
/**
 * Variable for the index of the intended targetItem which has to be selected.
 */
protected int intendedTargetItemIndex;

/**
 * Variable for the index of the selected targetItem.
 */
protected int selectedTargetItemIndex;

/**
 * Variable which stores the last target on which the feedback cursor was over
 */
protected int lastTargetIndex = -1;

/**
 * This variable stores the background color of the unselected targetItem.
 */
protected Color targetItemColor = Color.WHITE;

/**
 * This variable stores the color of the selected targetItem.
 */
protected Color targetItemSelectedColor = Color.BLUE;

/**
 * Variable for the number of selected test runs. Value is increased after a selection. Is used for the recordData method.
 */
protected int targetIndexCounter = 0;

/**
 * Variable represents the start time in milliseconds of a presented test run.
 * It is set when the intended targetItem is marked.
 */
protected long timeStart;

/**
 * Variable represents the end time in milliseconds of a presented test run.
 * It is set when the TriggerEvent was generated.
 */
protected long timeEnd;

/**
 * Stores the time needed for trigger a targetItem in milliseconds.
 */
protected long timeDuration;

/**
 * Variable represents the start time in CPU time ticks of a presented test run.
 * It is set when the intended targetItem is marked.
 */
protected long timeTickStart;

/**
 * Variable represents the end time in CPU time ticks of a presented test run.
 * It is set when the TriggerEvent was generated.
 */
protected long timeTickTriggered;

/**
 * Variable stores the last stored GazePoint to unmark it on the jPanel
 */
protected Point lastGazePointLocation = null;

/**
 * Variable stores a reference to the SelectionTriggerMechanism.
 */
protected SelectionTriggerMechanism selectionTriggerMechanism;

/**
 * Thread which processes the selection sequence.
 * Therefore another thread is used to speed up the system.
 */
protected Thread triggerThread;

/**
 * Thread which processes new received GazePointEvents.
 * Therefore another thread is used to speed up the system.
 */
protected Thread gazePointReceivedThread;

/**
 * Queue which stores new GazePointEvents. They are processed by the gazePointReceivedThread.
 */
protected ConcurrentLinkedDeque<GazePointEvent> concurrentGPEQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<GazePointEvent>();

/**
 * This XML element stores the recorded data for one TestPlanItem.
 */
protected Element recordedData = null;

/**
 * Standard constructor which initialized the BasicGazeTarget with standard values.
 * @param testManager as BasicGazeTarget owner
 * @param rawGazeDataProvider
 * @param filteredDataProvider
 */
public BasicGazeTarget(TestManager testManager, GazeDataProvider rawGazeDataProvider, FilteredDataProvider filteredDataProvider) {
    super(testManager, rawGazeDataProvider, filteredDataProvider);
    // BasicGazeTarget is initialized with the given standard values        
    initGazeTarget();
}

/**
 * Constructor which initialized the BasicGazeTarget with the values given in the basicGazeTargetTypeProperties list.
 * @param testManager as BasicGazeTarget owner
 * @param rawGazeDataProvider
 * @param filteredDataProvider
 * @param basicGazeTargetTypeProperties stores the concrete property values
 */
public BasicGazeTarget(TestManager testManager, GazeDataProvider rawGazeDataProvider, FilteredDataProvider filteredDataProvider, LinkedList<String> basicGazeTargetTypeProperties) {
    super(testManager, rawGazeDataProvider, filteredDataProvider);

    // read in the given properties for the BasicGazeTarget
    if (Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(0)) == 1) {
        this.feedBackCursor = true;
    } else {
        this.feedBackCursor = false;
    }
    this.numberOfTargetItems = Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(1));
    this.buttonHeightRatio = Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(2));
    this.deadSpace = Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(3));
    switch (basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(4)) {
    case "KeyboardKeyC":
        this.selectionTriggerType = SelectionTriggerType.KeyboardKeyC;
        break;
    case "DwellTime":
        this.selectionTriggerType = SelectionTriggerType.DwellTime;
        this.dwellTimeInMilliseconds = Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(5));
        this.dwellTimeAccuracy = Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(6));
        break;
    case "Wink":
        this.selectionTriggerType = SelectionTriggerType.Wink;
        this.winkTimeInMilliseconds = Integer.valueOf(basicGazeTargetTypeProperties.get(5));
        break;
    case "Speech":
        this.selectionTriggerType = SelectionTriggerType.Speech;
        break;
    }

    initGazeTarget();

}

/**
 * This method initializes the BasicGazeTarget. It registers the SelectionTriggerMechanism and starts Threads for concurrency.
 */
protected void initGazeTarget() {

    initJPanel();

    // is needed to handle simulated wink trigger with a clicked mouse
    if ((rawGazeDataProvider instanceof DummyGazeProvider) && rawGazeDataProvider != null) {                
        this.addMouseListener((DummyGazeProvider) rawGazeDataProvider);
    } else if ((filteredDataProvider instanceof DummyGazeProvider) && filteredDataProvider != null) {
        this.addMouseListener((DummyGazeProvider) filteredDataProvider);
    }

    // create the SelectionTriggerMechanism
    switch (selectionTriggerType.toString()) {
    case "KeyboardKeyC":
        selectionTriggerMechanism = new KeyboardTriggerMechanism(this);
        break;
    case "DwellTime":
        if (rawGazeDataProvider!=null) {
            selectionTriggerMechanism = new DwellTimeTriggerMechanism(rawGazeDataProvider,dwellTimeInMilliseconds,trackerFrequency,dwellTimeAccuracy);
        } else if (filteredDataProvider!=null){
            selectionTriggerMechanism = new DwellTimeTriggerMechanism(filteredDataProvider,dwellTimeInMilliseconds,trackerFrequency,dwellTimeAccuracy);
        }               
        break;
    case "Wink":
        if (rawGazeDataProvider!=null) {
            selectionTriggerMechanism = new WinkTriggerMechanism(rawGazeDataProvider,winkTimeInMilliseconds);
        } else if (filteredDataProvider!=null){
            selectionTriggerMechanism = new WinkTriggerMechanism(filteredDataProvider,winkTimeInMilliseconds);
        }
        break;
    case "Speech":
        selectionTriggerMechanism = new SpeechTriggerMechanism();
        break;
    }       
    log.info(System.currentTimeMillis() + " - " + "Created SelectionTriggerMechanism " + selectionTriggerType.toString());

    // create a new thread which is responsible for the TriggerEvents
    triggerThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {                   
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        log.log(Level.SEVERE,null, e);
                    }
                    selectionTriggered();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    triggerThread.start();

    // initialize FutureGazeReaders if the storeFutureGazeData flag is set
    if (storeFutureGazeData) {          
        if (rawGazeDataProvider != null) {
            rawGazeDataFuture = new FutureGazeReader(rawGazeDataProvider,BasicGazeTarget.this);
        }
        if (filteredDataProvider != null) {
            filteredGazeDataFuture = new FutureGazeReader(filteredDataProvider,BasicGazeTarget.this);
        }                   
    }

    // create a new thread which is responsible for processing the received GazePoints
    gazePointReceivedThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        log.log(Level.SEVERE,null, e);
                    }
                    while (!concurrentGPEQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        processReceivedGazePointEvent(concurrentGPEQueue.remove());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    gazePointReceivedThread.start();
    this.setFocusable(true);
}

/**
 * This method creates the targetItems on the BasicGazeTarget panel.
 * @return 
 */

protected void initJPanel() {   


    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.pack();
     frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    Color backgroundOfPanel61 = new Color(64,173,95);
    Color backgroundOfPanel62 = new Color(212,42,42);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 50);

    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    enter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    clear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));

    a.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    g.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    h.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    i.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    j.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
    k.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));

     final JLabel countLabel =new JLabel("");
     final JLabel timeLabel =new JLabel("");
     JLabel selectLabel =new JLabel("Select the interval:  ");
     JLabel toLabel =new JLabel(" to ");
     final JLabel correctAnswer = new JLabel("0");
     final JLabel wrongAnswer = new JLabel("0");

     JTextField interval1= new JTextField(4);
     JTextField interval2= new JTextField(4);

     //invisible panel
     JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
     //new frame object
     JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
     JPanel panel61 = new JPanel();
     JPanel panel62 = new JPanel();
     //creating new frame
     final JFrame gameOver = new JFrame();

    //creating panels
     JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(); // types + levels
        JPanel panel11 = new JPanel(); // types
        JPanel panel12 = new JPanel(); // levels
     JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(); //  question + answer + label of input + input + start & stop buttons
        JPanel panel21 = new JPanel(); // question + answer
            JPanel panel211 = new JPanel(); // question
            JPanel panel212 = new JPanel(); // answer

        JPanel panel22 = new JPanel();  // label of input + input
        JPanel panel23 = new JPanel();  // start & stop button
     JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(); // correct count + time spent
        JPanel panel31 = new JPanel();  // correct count
        JPanel panel32 = new JPanel();  // time spent
    //we create panel4 outside of constructor
    JPanel panel5 = new JPanel(); //invisble panel4 + panel2

     ImageIcon mainimg;     
     mainimg = new ImageIcon(("C:\\Users\\sony\\Desktop\\Thesis Work\\images\\minion.png"));
     minion = new JLabel(mainimg);
     panel22.add(minion);   

     ImageIcon img;
     img = new ImageIcon(("C:\\Users\\sony\\Desktop\\Thesis Work\\images\\applesicon.png"));
     apples = new JLabel(img);
     apples1 = new JLabel(img);
     panel22.add(apples);   
     panel22.add(apples1);
     apples.setVisible(false);
     apples1.setVisible(false);

     ImageIcon tickimg;
     tickimg = new ImageIcon(("C:\\Users\\sony\\Desktop\\Thesis Work\\images\\tick.png"));
     tick = new JLabel(tickimg);
     panel22.add(tick);
     tick.setVisible(false);

     ImageIcon incorrectimg;
     incorrectimg = new ImageIcon(("C:\\Users\\sony\\Desktop\\Thesis Work\\images\\incorrect.png"));
     incorrect = new JLabel(incorrectimg);
     panel22.add(incorrect);
     incorrect.setVisible(false);

     //setting panel4 to invisible
     panel4.setVisible(false);
     //adding borders
     panel11.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Questions (Select an alphabet for a question to be displayed)"));
     panel12.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Input Buttons"));
     panel31.setBorder(new TitledBorder("No. of Correct Answers"));
     panel32.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Time Spent"));
     //layouts (the others are flow layout by default)
     panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panel11.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        panel12.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));  
        panel21.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,5));
            panel211.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));      
            panel212.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));  
    panel5.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   

    panel12.add(button1);
    panel12.add(button2);
    panel12.add(button3);
    panel12.add(button4);
    panel12.add(button5);
    panel12.add(button6);
    panel12.add(button7);
    panel12.add(button8);
    panel12.add(button9);
    panel12.add(enter);
    panel12.add(button0);
    panel12.add(clear);

    panel11.add(a); 
    panel11.add(b);
    panel11.add(c);
    panel11.add(d);
    panel11.add(f);
    panel11.add(g);
    panel11.add(h);
    panel11.add(i);
    panel11.add(j);
    panel11.add(k);

     panel212.add(shownLabel);
     panel22.add(input);    
     input.setVisible(false);

     panel23.add(startButton);
     panel23.add(stopButton);

     panel31.add(countLabel);
     panel32.add(timeLabel);

     panel4.add(selectLabel);
     panel4.add(interval1);
     panel4.add(toLabel);
     panel4.add(interval2);

     panel1.add(panel11);
     panel1.add(panel12);

     panel21.add(panel211);
     panel21.add(panel212);
     panel2.add(panel21);
     panel2.add(panel22);
     panel2.add(panel23);

     panel3.add(panel31);
     panel3.add(panel32);

     panel5.add(panel4, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     panel5.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

     //adding panel to frame     
     add(panel3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //START OF NEW FRAME
        //designing new frame (colors, font, etc...)
         correctAnswer.setFont(font);
         correctAnswer.setForeground(Color.white);
         wrongAnswer.setFont(font);
         wrongAnswer.setForeground(Color.white);
         panel61.setBackground(backgroundOfPanel61);    
         panel62.setBackground(backgroundOfPanel62);

         //titledborders of new frame
         TitledBorder titledBorder2 = new TitledBorder("Correct Answer");
         titledBorder2.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
         panel61.setBorder(titledBorder2);

         TitledBorder titledBorder3 = new TitledBorder("Wrong Answer");
         titledBorder3.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
         panel62.setBorder(titledBorder3);

        //layout of new frame's panel
        panel6.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,10,10));

        //adding objects to panel and panel to frame
        panel61.add(correctAnswer);
        panel62.add(wrongAnswer);
        panel6.add(panel61);
        panel6.add(panel62);
        gameOver.add(panel6);

        //frame settings
        gameOver.setTitle("Congratulations !!!!");
        gameOver.setVisible(false);
        gameOver.setSize(470,150);
        gameOver.setLocationRelativeTo(null);            

        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finishTime= System.currentTimeMillis(); // getting stopped time
                timeSpent= finishTime - startTime; // calculating time spent
                long realTime = timeSpent/1000; // converting to readible time (because it is miliseconds)
                String stringtimeSpent = Long.toString(realTime); // converting float to string
                timeLabel.setText(stringtimeSpent+" seconds"); // setting timeLabel



                correctAnswer.setText(""+correctCount); // showing correct for both jframes
                wrongAnswer.setText(""+wrongCount);// showing correct for new jframes

                input.setText(""); // clearing input after user pressed stop button     
                shownLabel.setText("Welcome ! Kindly Press the'Play' button to start the game"); // clearing label after user pressed stop button  

                gameOver.setVisible(true); //showing the game over frame
                input.setVisible(false); 
                apples.setVisible(false);
                apples1.setVisible(false);
                banana.setVisible(false);
                minion.setVisible(true);
                bird.setVisible(false);
                bird1.setVisible(false);
                bird2.setVisible(false);
                bird3.setVisible(false);
                bird4.setVisible(false);
                seven1.setVisible(false);
                three1.setVisible(false);
                basket.setVisible(false);
                bad.setVisible(false);
                foot.setVisible(false);
                choc.setVisible(false);
                choc1.setVisible(false);
                choc2.setVisible(false);
                burger.setVisible(false);
                hulk.setVisible(false);
                iron.setVisible(false);
                ironman.setVisible(false);
                joker.setVisible(false);
                thor.setVisible(false);
                capamerica.setVisible(false);
                saturn.setVisible(false);
                neptune.setVisible(false);
                venus.setVisible(false);
                moon.setVisible(false);
                uranus.setVisible(false);
                mercury.setVisible(false);
                earth.setVisible(false);
                eight1.setVisible(false);
                nine1.setVisible(false);
                four1.setVisible(false);
                six1.setVisible(false);
                two1.setVisible(false);
                deadpool.setVisible(false);
                magneto.setVisible(false);
                superman.setVisible(false);
                venom.setVisible(false);
                spidey.setVisible(false);
                hellboy.setVisible(false);
                batman.setVisible(false);
                wolverine.setVisible(false);
                tick.setVisible(false);
                startButton.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                shownLabel.setText(question); // changing question label
                startTime= System.currentTimeMillis(); // starting to get time after pressing start button
                startButton.setVisible(false);
                stopButton.setVisible(false);
                // clearing counts after re-play
                correctCount = 0; 
                wrongCount = 0;
                countLabel.setText("");
                timeLabel.setText("");
                input.setText("");
                input.setVisible(false);
                minion.setVisible(false);
                cheer.setVisible(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                a.setEnabled(true);
                b.setEnabled(true);
                c.setEnabled(true);
                d.setEnabled(true);
                f.setEnabled(true);
                g.setEnabled(true);
                h.setEnabled(true);
                i.setEnabled(true);
                j.setEnabled(true);
                k.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });


        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 if(e.getSource()==button1)
                        input.setText(input.getText().concat("1"));             
            }
        });
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 if(e.getSource()==button2)
                        input.setText(input.getText().concat("2"));             
            }
        });

        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e.getSource()==clear)
                    input.setText("");
            }
        });

        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            private double inputvalue;  

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e.getSource()==enter)
                inputvalue = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());

                if(inputvalue == result)
                {
                    correctCount++;
                    String stringcount = Integer.toString(correctCount); // getting integer to string
                    countLabel.setText(stringcount);
                    tick.setVisible(true);
                    incorrect.setVisible(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    wrongCount++;
                    input.setText("");
                    incorrect.setVisible(true);
                    tick.setVisible(false);
                }

            shownLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,29));
            startButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 27));
            stopButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 27));
            timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
            countLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));

            _targetItems.add(startButton);
            _targetItems.add(a);
```

Comment: It's not urgent to us. I've edited your title so it doesn't attract quite so many downvotes simply for that.

Comment: show your code to let us understand what's wrong with your code

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you might want to use JToggleButtons.

Comment: I have uploaded the code above

Comment: @AndyTurner the samaritan :)

Comment: That's quite a lot of code there. Could you try to show a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem is what I have stated above regarding the linked list.